# Mobile Wifi Hotspot auto disables if there is too bandwidth used

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, xiaomi, wifi-tethering, redmi

I have a Redmi Note 11 Pro 5G and mobile wifi hotspot auto disables if there is too bandwidth used. Maybe it's done to avoid overheating. How to avoid this? Is there a workaround? I really need to have a stable connection I can't have an hotspot that auto-disables.
Happens usually when it's very used in terms of bandwidth and people connected.